# Spring - validate input inside Controller against a bean

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, jsr

I have a controller that uses payload to perform some actions, but now I would like to validate it before performing any operations. The payload is converted to `byte[]` and then read into a class called AuthorizationServer, which has some validation annotations - @NotNull, @NotBlank etc.

This is a block from the class AuthorizationServer:

```
@NotBlank
private String authorizationServerId;

@Property
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NotBlank
private String authorizationUrl;

@Property(policy = PojomaticPolicy.TO_STRING)
@NotBlank
private String clientAuthorizationUrl;

@NotBlank
private String deviceRootCert;
```

This is the controller:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream());
        String signature = authorization.split(":")[1];

        ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapper();
        AuthorizationServer authorizationServer = mapper.readValue(bytes, 
        AuthorizationServer.class);
```

Now, in the next line, I would like to validate the authorizationServer against the annotations declared in AuthorizationServer class. I am on Spring 4. Can someone please guide me? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have spring unmarshal the AuthorizationServer class for you?  Then you would just annotate it with @Valid and look at the BindingResult object for errors:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/somUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void doSomething(@RequestBody @Valid AuthorizationServer authorizationServer, BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
           //do something
        }
```

Update:

Try this code to programmatically validate:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<AuthorizationServer>> errors = validator.validate(authorizationServer);
```

Update 2:

What about this:

```
@Valid
AuthorizationServer authorizationServer = mapper.readValue(bytes, AuthorizationServer.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, but however I can't unmarshal the stream into an AuthorizationServer object. Is there a way to do it inside the method, but not with the arguments?

Comment: That works, thank you, but I am not supposed to use the ValidatorFactory. Is there a way where we can use Validator and invoke validate( ) method based on some rules?

Comment: Thank you again, but it says "@Valid not applicable to local variable" :(