# How do I use @Valid to validate local variables?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

This is a followup from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618602/spring-validate-input-inside-controller-against-a-bean). How do I add `@Valid` to a local variable?

Here is code from the class `AuthorizationServer`:

```
@NotBlank
private String authorizationServerId;

@Property
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NotBlank
private String authorizationUrl;

@Property(policy = PojomaticPolicy.TO_STRING)
@NotBlank
private String clientAuthorizationUrl;

@NotBlank
private String deviceRootCert;
```

This is the controller:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream());
        String signature = authorization.split(":")[1];

        ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapper();
        AuthorizationServer authorizationServer = mapper.readValue(bytes, 
        AuthorizationServer.class);
```

How do I validate the `authorizationServer` against the annotations declared in the `AuthorizationServer` class?

When I tried

```
@Valid
AuthorizationServer authorizationServer = mapper.readValue(bytes, AuthorizationServer.class);
```

I got the error `@Valid not applicable to local variable`.

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception says it all. Bean Validation does not allow the validation local variables. It is all about validating class state via property validation or you can do method validation. There is no such thing as local variable validation.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, **Bean Validation** does not allow the validation of local variables. However, you can do something like this:

```
@javax.validation.executable.ValidateOnExecution    
AuthorizationServer getAuthorizationServer(ObjectMapper mapper){
    return mapper.readValue(bytes, AuthorizationServer.class);
}
```